# Program won't quit at correct time

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to ask the user whether they want to see a book, and then asking if they know the story. I the want to then tell the user how many stories they know out of how many attempts.
Unfortunately the program won't quit at the correct time.

```
# Set count list to zero    
    
count_y = 0
count_all = 0
    
# Asking the user whether they want to see a book
exit = False
while not exit:
    user_input = input('Enter s to see a book and q to quit: ')
    if user_input == 'q':
        exit = True
    elif user_input == 's':
        show_book()

# I am trying to tell the user how many stories they knew out of their total attempts.

          
    user_answer = input('Did you know the stories? Press Y or N: ')
    if user_answer == 'y':
       count_y = count_y + 1 
    elif user_answer == 'y' or 'n':
       count_all = count_all + 1
            
# print the result to the user.
print('You knew',(count_y), 'out of', (count_all), 'stories .')
```

Comment: While I have no idea what language this is (did you forget to add a tag to the question for what programming language this is?), what do you mean by "won't quit at the correct time"? Is is because you don't skip the rest of the loop body and go ahead and ask them "Did you know the stories"? If so, you need to change how your if/else is working.

Comment: Hi sorry, its python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "a == x or y or z" always evaluate to True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true)

Comment: Hi, i don't think so as i am trying to add the total of times the user presses 'y' if they know the story, and the total of books seen, and print both results.

Answer (score 0):

Your code keeps running because you just set exit to true and don't set a break or continue underneath (Your program will finish this iteration). You can also put the code below in the elif block (if that works for you) I think there is also a piece missing in the middle so I can't tell 100%.

```
    if user_input == 'q':
        break
```

Comment: Hi, adding in the break after both sets of code seems to work, i am sure there much more neat and efficient ways than i have written, but Thank you!!

Comment: I'm glad to have helped you.

Answer (score 0):

1. `exit` is a built-in function. I think it's better to rename the parameter.
2. In the current script, you're asking the user if the story is known even when "q" is choose. You can rewrite it as below, or simply puts a `break` as @rowBee said.
3. I also think it's simpler and cleaner to update `count_all` outside the if-statement.

```
count_y = 0
count_all = 0

to_exit = False
while not to_exit:
    user_input = input('...')
    if user_input == 'q':
        to_exit = True
    elif user_input == 's':
        show_book()
        count_all += 1
        user_answer = input('...')
        if user_answer == 'y':
            count_y += 1

print('...')
```